# Garbage collection in Java clustering

Tags: java, heap-memory

I am running a program for k-medoide clustering. I build a function to assign cluster to every object then I run a function to update center. I have a nested loop and in loop every time I am accessing from data base. but I updating center function I am getting an error like this

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1438)         at
>    java.util.regex.Pattern.(Pattern.java:1130)         at
>    java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:822)         at
>    java.lang.String.split(String.java:2293)         at
>    java.lang.String.split(String.java:2335)         at
>    dtamining_project_rabia.kMeanMapper.updatecenter(kMeanMapper.java:233)
>    at dtamining_project_rabia.Main.main(Main.java:21) Java Result: 1

I dont know where my memory leaks are although I am not storing data in object but accessing every time from data base.

Answer (score 1):

[generate a heap dump](http://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/heap_dumps_are_back_with) when the program throws the OOME.  the get a program which allows you to analyze the heap dump (jhat, netbeans, jvisualvm, yjp, etc.) to determine what is causing the OOME.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase heap space.

Comment: but its not a good solution.... Every time i will increase space every time it will be full.... :(